# Doxygen: xrefitem key works with '\' but not with '@' in the documentation

Tags: alias, doxygen

The below is my ALIASES configuration in my Doxyfile

```
ALIASES                = "In=\par Changes in version:" \
                         "WindowsSpecific=\xrefitem WindowsSpecific \"\" \"\"" \
                         "LinuxSpecific=\xrefitem LinuxSpecific \"\" \"\""
```

In my program, if I provide the custom tag with backslash symbol, Doxygen generates the output properly

```
/**
 * \WindowsSpecific
 * @In 1.0.1
 */
int getVersion();
```

I can see a "WindowsSpecific" item in "Related pages".

However, if I provide the custom tag with @ symbol

```
/**
 * @WindowsSpecific
 * @In 1.0.1
 */
int getVersion();
```

I do not get the output i.e. Related page with "WindowsSpecific" as desired. I am using doxygen v 1.8.13

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.13 is quite old (December 29, 2016), the current version is 1.9.1 so definitely worthwhile to update. Regarding the problem, I tried with doxygen 1.8.13 a Doxyfile with the mentioned content and a file `aa.h` with the content with the `@` and I do see the related page "WindowsSpecific" (I also see it when I use the backslash version.

Comment: Tried it with Doxygen 1.9.1 as well. Same result :(

Comment: Without further information it is not possible to comment further as I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think the only difference is I generated for a CS (C#) file and you generated it for a .h header.

Comment: Might be very important information, but this does not make a difference for me (note that for a `.cs` file I added `\file` in a separate comment at the tot to be sure the file is processed).

Comment: Ah well, thank you for the attempts.. Somehow it is not working for me :(

Comment: We should find out what do differently (important for other users as well). As you have also doxygen version 1.9.1 it is good to publish the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` and of course the exact small file you used.